# No module named in Django error migration

Tags: django, database-migration

I am using the command on MacOS to migrate database

```
(myenv) (base) Elenas-MacBook-Air:myenv elenaorlova$ python3 manage.py migrate
```

But as a result getting an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
main()
File "manage.py", line 17, in main
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in 
_find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'changers.app'
```

Could you please let me know if you have an idea why is that happening?

Thank you!

Comment: `changers.app` is probably an entry in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting. I don’t think it’s a common Django app, so we can’t tell what the issue is from the error.

Comment: I guess the name of the app is wrong here, as @Alasdair mentioned, you can check `settings.py` file. You can remove or change the record with working one. We can help you if you share folder hierarchy and `INSTALLED_APPS` part of settings file.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and very fast response! Please find the link to my hierarchy https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OpXK1g7R95WRk-adcu_Y6EJb7LfX0Sbn

Comment: `INSTALLED_APPS = ['changers.app.ChangersConfig', [...]` can just be `INSTALLED_APPS = ['changers', [...]` in your settings.py file.

Comment: I see the problem now, it should be `apps`, not `app`. Or you could change it to `'changers'` as Ben suggested.

Comment: Thank you all very much! Really helps. Now I am facing No module named 'psycopg2', but I guess it is because of incorrect installation of psycopg2. Thank you!